# Curl package not installing

Tags: r, curl, rstudio-server

while installing curl package

```
install.packages("curl")
Installing package into ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 367047 bytes (358 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 358 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
’
```

after this i installed the libcurl package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libcurl4-openssl-dev/download. Then i also copy the whole packae folder into the library folder of r. Still while installing the curl package tis erroe comes

```
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libcurl' found
    Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libcurl' found
    Using PKG_CFLAGS=
    Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
    ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
    **Configuration failed because libcurl was not found**. Try installing:
     * deb: **libcurl4-openssl-dev** (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
     * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
     * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
    If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
    PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
    is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
    R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
    * removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status

    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpmQeo3q/downloaded_packages
```

Where is it that i am wrong? Different packages like shiny and ggplot were all downloaded and loaded in the same way. Could anybody help?
This is happening because i have to finally install the quantmod package but it gives that curl dependency could not be installed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

libcurl4-openssl-dev is not a R package, but rather a linux library.

In a console type:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Note: you need sudo powers.

Answer in [Configuration failed because libcurl was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115972/configuration-failed-because-libcurl-was-not-found/42117480)