# How to update RCurl and curl to the version on the host machine?

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

Initially I was trying to use `devtools::install_github("EdwinTh/padr")` where I got the following error:

`Error in curl::new_handle() : An unknown option was passed in to libcurl`

After some time I found out that `devtools` uses `curl/RCurl` which wraps the current version of `curl`on the host machine.

The host(Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) machine version of `curl` is:

`1$ curl -V
curl 7.61.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libssh2/1.8.0 librtmp/2.3`

where `curl`is located in:

`12$ which curl
/usr/local/bin/curl`

and is working fine when using `curl::new_handle()`directly from the terminal

In comparison the `curl/RCurl` version is:

```
> RCurl::curlVersion()
$age
[1] 3

$version
[1] "7.35.0"`
```

I'm assuming that this might be the underlying issue. My problem now is how to let Rs `curl/RCurl` point to the corresponding version.

I have tried everything I found so far on that topic for `R` like:

`install.packages("RCurl", type="source")` and 
`install.packages("curl", type="source")`

as well as adjusting `curl`on the host machine:

```
wget https://libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.8.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf llibssh2-1.8.0.tar.gz
cd libssh2-1.8.0
./configure
make
sudo make install 

wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.61.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf curl-7.61.0.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.61.0
./configure --with-libssh2=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

But I always get the same version for `curl/RCurl` 7.35.0 instead of 7.61.0.

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: For starters, you could consider not being on a four-year old release of your distro.  With Ubuntu 18.04 you have no such problem.  But in short: update the `libcurl*-dev` package (complications: there are several) and the reinstall `RCurl` and/or `curl`.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel there are some restrictions hindering to upgrade Ubuntu. But anyway, thanks for taking time to give your opinion. `libcurl*-dev` was already installed. So basically I removed it and reinstalled  `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` as well as those two packages without any change in the behaviour.

Comment: If you tell Ubuntu to install from 14.04 it will of _install the same package over and over_. That is what sticking with a release means.  Your problem, in essence, is to figure out where to get a newer curl library _built for that release_ from.  And/or how to tell the R packages how to prefer the local one.

Comment: Hmm, I just assumed it is related somehow to the Path for curl /usr/bin/curl vs. /user/local/bin/curl. I thought RCurl or curl in R are referring to /usr/bin/curl. However on `echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:` the `/usr/local/bin`comes before `/usr/bin` where I have installed the newest curl  7.61.0. running with out errors.

Comment: The binary is not used to build the R package.

Comment: was this ever resolved? same situation, but i've also downloaded the RCurl source, extracted, run ./configure, built and installed and still no good

Comment: So the only way is to update the OS version and update curl?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, and ran into the same problem when I tried and failed to install the Tidyerse R package. As a dependency it tried to install curl 4.3 although I have already curl 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.12 installed. So to update the OS wouldn't help as long as R doesn't realize there is already an existing curl version installed.

Solved it for me: sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev and sudo apt install libssl-dev